# Getting an error mesasge "this.TakeScreenshot is not a function " in protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have written a function TakeScreenshot in a JS file say base.js file which save screenshot and return me the screenshot path The implementation as below.

```
this.TakeScreenshot = function(screenShotName) {
//some stuff.....
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            var stream = fs.createWriteStream(screenshotPath);
            stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
            stream.end();
    });
        return screenshotPath;
    };

I am calling the above function in another function called "isTruelyPresent". This function will take a screenshot if element is present/not present on UI. The implementation is as below:

this.isTrulyPresent = function(elementToCheckVisibilityOf, element2) {
          return elementToCheckVisibilityOf.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayedd) {
          var myObj;
          myObj = this.TakeScreenshot(element2);
          // some stuff
          console.log('isDisplayed'+isDisplayedd);
          return isDisplayedd;
    }).then(null, function (error) {
          var myObj;
          myObj = this.TakeScreenshot("ErrorSS");
          console.log('A NoSuchElement exception was throw because the element is NOT displayed so we return false');
          return false;
        });  
    };


Protractor script is throwing an error "this.TakeScreenshot is not a function". Could any one please help me to resolve the issue.
```

Comment: Note: isTrulyPresent function is present in the same JS file (base.js)

Comment: in the asynchronous programming, you cannot use `this` keyword inside a callback method. Instead, declare a new variable inside the function scope and assign `this` to the newly created variable. In your case, Inside `isTrulyPresent` method create a variable like `var self =this;` and use `self.TakeScreenshot()` to call the method.

Comment: Thanks @SudharsanSelvaraj.. Your help is much appreciated. I will try your solution and get back to you If I have any issues. Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: Hi @SudharsanSelvaraj. I tried your solution. Once again I got the same error.

Saying " Failed: myObj.TakeScreenshot is not a function"

// This is how I written in my code
var myObj = this; 
myObj.TakeScreenshot('error'));

Answer (score 0):

First of all be aware that there is a difference between `isPresent` (checks if an element is present in the DOM) and `isDisplayed` (checks if an element is present in the DOM AND visible). If an element is not present in the DOM, the method `isDisplayed()` will fail hard. You are now catching this error, is this also what you want?

Secondly each `function` can have it's own `this` scope. That means that your `this.TakeScreenshot("ErrorSS")` can have a reference to the `this`-scope of the `function(error){}` instead of the `this` you want to refer to.

This ;-) [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) may help in fixing this. What I normally use are the `arrow`-functions, see the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. The doc have more information. Definitely it helps me.

Comment: No  @wswebcreation. I have no luck :(